# Run jenkins in browser gave 404 error

Tags: java, jenkins, continuous-deployment

new to jenkins, I've just installed it on my windows machine (under C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins). [The tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Jenkins/article.html) says that it runs on http://localhost:8080/ but I get a 404 when trying. I presume it needs to be started somehow, so I believe I attempted to start it from the window console with `java -jar jenkins*.war` but I get an error in the actual console:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins>java -jar jenkins*.war
Error: Unable to access jarfile jenkins*.war
```

Am I trying from the wrong folder? Does anybody have any suggestion? thanks

Edit: The .war file is definitely there:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins>dir *.war
 Volume in drive C is Windows
Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins

16/11/2016  07:54        69,764,788 jenkins.war
               1 File(s)     69,764,788 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  146,485,506,048 bytes free

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins>java -jar jenkins*.war
Error: Unable to access jarfile jenkins*.war

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins>
```

Comment: run it without the asterisk `java -jar jenkins.war` (will only work from the dir where the file is (better use absolute path `java -jar "C:\Jenkins\jenkins.war"`). Also there is a log in the directory where the `war` file is. Look in it, see if Jenkins actually started
Also, try putting it in `C:\Jenkins` that will exclude any permission problems (will always run as admin). Like mentioned below, [Run it as a service][1].

[1]: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Windows+service

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you are in the right directory.

If you run `dir *.war` in your console window, you should see the Jenkins war file.  If you do not see it, you are not in the right directory.

If you can't see it, you need to figure out where it is and then:

`cd c:\location\of\jenkins' and re-run the`dir *.war` command to verify it is in the current directory.

If you need help finding the war file, see here for how to use the find command from the Windows command line:

http://www.howtogeek.com/206097/how-to-use-find-from-the-windows-command-prompt/

Comment: OK I restarted my machine and now it seems to work. The installation process was correct and everything was where it was supposed to be, but I was never asked to reboot my machine after the installation process.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the Windows installer and install as service? That should be the easiest way, and then go to Windows services and make sure Jenkins service is running.

Comment: thanks guys.yes I run the installer, now I checked in Services, found Jenkins and started the process manually (so it's now running as it says "started" under status), but I still get the 404 message when I browse to http://localhost:8080/.
I also verified that the .war is in there the directory is correct, the .war file is in there, but for whatever reason it won't access it. (I updated the main thread with the result of the commands you wanted me to run)